# Is this a safe way to do two key encryption to store a third party password?

Tags: node.js, encryption

I'm building a system that connects to a third party api, and I have to store passwords for each of our users connected to that api. I need to make sure that the passwords are stored securely, so I don't want to trust the user's password as an encryption key. But I also need to make sure that we need the user to authenticate the use of this password, by entering their password.

I had the idea of creating a key by combining the user's id and password with a secret key on the server (just by concatenating them all). I then use crypto's [createCipher](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipher_algorithm_password) with `aes256` and the new generated key to encrypt the third party password and send it off to storage.

I noticed the text in the `createCipher` documentation that says this:

> In line with OpenSSL's recommendation to use pbkdf2 instead of EVP_BytesToKey it is recommended that developers derive a key and IV on their own using crypto.pbkdf2() and to use crypto.createCipheriv() to create the Cipher object.

And I read up about IVs and the attacks they are meant to prevent (still pretty confused about how that works, especially with my use case) but I think that since this will technically be using a different key every time, that will be a non-issue.

Is this kosher? Is there some vulnerability of this system that I'm missing?

Comment: You should still use an IV, simply just pick a random one each time you encrypt and prepend it to the ciphertext.  It doesn't need to be hidden.  You should probably encrypt twice rather than build a key from two other keys.  Encrypt once with first key and again with the second.  Thus you know for sure that your system is at least as secure as using just one of those keys.

Comment: Should I use the same IV for both encryption steps?

Comment: No.  Use two different IVs.

Comment: I tried doing this, and apparently node's createCipheriv only accepts keys and IVs of length 16. Is there a recommended way to use an arbitrary length password with this function, the way I could with the non-iv version? I considered hashing the password to get a fixed-length key, but I decided that wouldn't be secure as the password hash is saved elsewhere in the database.

Comment: It also seems like a 16 length key wouldn't be very secure... My instinct was to go for a 64 length key.

Comment: An IV is not a key and does not need to be kept secret.  It is 16 bytes long because that is the block size of AES.  You can't have a key that is 64 bytes long.  The largest key size accepted by AES is 32 bytes for AES256.  If you have two arbitrary length passwords, apply PBKDF2 to each of them first to derive a 32 byte key from each.  Then encrypt twice.

Comment: Also, and with respect, you aren't really in a position to say what key sizes are secure and which aren't.  A 16 byte key is more than secure.

Comment: I never claimed that I was in a position to claim that a key length is secure or not, but using a 16 character key did go against my (non-expert) intuition which says "use a nice long key with high entropy", so I figured it was worth mentioning because I could be missing something. I think the part that I missed was that you use PBKDF2 to generate the *key*. I was using it to generate the IV, and then I wasn't sure what I was supposed to use as a key anymore.

Comment: So if PBKDF2 is used to derive a key, then I guess I will need to save the salt somewhere as well, correct?

Comment: I didn't mean to cause offense, apologies.  Yes, PBKDF2 for the key(s) not the IV.  An IV is useless if it is not random, so you should be generating your IV(s) using a CSPRNG each time you encrypt.  You can use a static salt if you wish.  You aren't using PBKDF2 for hashing the passwords so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Is it normal to use the IV as the salt for PBKDF2, or should I generate that separately as well?

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I was near to pulling my hair out over this.

Comment: There are some abnormal interactions you could run into if you use the IV as a salt for PBKDF2 (you have to generate and use them in the exact correct order).  Generally it is best to not overlap parameters to each cryptosystem you are using.  You have two applications of PBKDF2 and then your two applications of AES.  It's best to not to duplicate any parameters between each simply because you will eliminate any unintended interactions.